# Why activerecord is mapping unassigned foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am mapping my foreign key by declaring it in the class.
But rails is calling auto assigned foreign key and throwing error as,

**unknown column in where clause**
Class declaration is given below,

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :criteria  
  self.primary_key = 'sup_id'  
end  

class Criteria < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :supplier, :foreign_key => "crt_sup_id"  
  self.primary_key = 'crt_id'  
  self.table_name = 'criterias'  
end
```

If I am using self.supplier in class Criteria it is working fine

but If I am using self.criteria in class Supplier then error thrown as,

Unknown column 'criterias.supplier_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `criterias`.* FROM `criterias`  WHERE `criterias`.`supplier_id`

I don't have a field named supplier_id in criterias instead I am using crt_sup_id as defined in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference the foreign key in the `has_one` relation as well :

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :criteria, foreign_key: "crt_sup_id"   
  self.primary_key = 'sup_id'  
end
```

The reason is that by default associations are one-way in rails. See [the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference) for more information.

Comment: When doing so I am getting another error                    NoMethodError (undefined method `crt_sup_id' for #<Supplier:0x00000015f58560>):

Comment: WTF ? did you paste exactly the same code ? Did you try using the old hash syntax `:foreign_key => "crt_sup_id"` ?

Comment: I am sorry, the problem is some of my supplier objects doesn't have criteria. How can I modify my relation to meet this?

Comment: did you reload your console / server ? Normally, if one of your Suppliers doesn't have a criteria, `supplier.criteria` should return nil.

Comment: I tried with console reload. Still the same error. The reason is I need to show one of the related attribute in a grid and if the relation fails to fetch record then error is thrown.

Comment: Also when I am saving Supplier, Criteria is not saved even if autosave is set to true.

Comment: these are different concerns. You should open new questions, one for each problem, i'll be pleased to help.